# Should I mention my long term goal is starting a business?

Tags: manager, performance-reviews, meetings

I have my annual review meeting coming up and one of the questions is the following:

- What are your longer term goals? (one to two years from now)

Truly, my answer is that I would like to have my own business in the next couple years. I'm actively working toward this in my freetime too.

I'm not sure if I should answer it in that way. I'm thinking that I should probably answer it related to the company I work in specifically, e.g. pursing a higher position or leading a project. I really enjoy my job and would be thrilled to work in it, if I was unable to start a business in the next couple years.

So, should I mention my long term goal of starting a business?

*Side note: The business I work for is very large company, 6000+ employees. The business I would like to create would not compete in anyway with my current company.*

Comment: My recommendation is to announce things that only change your status. Otherwise they're left to speculate and that's never a good thing.

Comment: Depending on what "actively working towards [your own business] in my freetime" means... I would suggest you check any company restrictions on non-competes, ownership of IP created during your tenure, conflict of interest activities etc. I say this even though I have seen your note that your possible own business wouldn't compete with your employer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though I always advocate for transparency and honesty, in this case, I don't see any benefits for mentioning this, if you're quite sure you will be leaving the company in the next year or two. If you say that's your plan, your employer will, most likely, avoid giving you any long-term positions or responsibilities and place the bet on some other employee they believe will be a better investment over time.

What you can do instead, is to try to mention things you'd like to focus on in the long term that would eventually help you when you start your own company. For example, if at the moment you don't manage people and you plan to have employees in your business, you can mention that you're looking to become a leader or manager. By doing this, you don't burn your chances of progression and learning, and you'll get a lot of tools and experience that will come in handy when finally starting your business.

Answer (score 6):

One or two years is well within the scope of a normal decision-timeline about raises and promotions.

**Don't tell your employer you are leaving within such a scope**

because a solid raise and promotion is often an gamble on the part of the company: not worth it in the short term but quite possibly great in a few years.

By telling them you will leave within the "not worth it" time you are disqualifying yourself from all but the most meager raises.

You could tell them but pretend it is a long-term idea you have. It does show you have some ambition and might be interested in a more leadership-oriented role.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, in a situation like this I’d answer the question with an unspoken “[Assuming you were to stay here permanently], what would be your longer term goals?”

Answer (score 3):

100% No. When they ask about your long term goals, that means your long term goals within the company. Goals that working for the company will help you achieve.

If they ask long term goals personally, you talk about areas that you want to learn or improve on that are related to your position in the company.

The last thing they want to hear is that you plan on leaving them to setup another business.

Answer (score 0):

No. Answer related to the company and continue your work on your side project in your free time.

Why? You can’t know what is on in your life in one to two years. What is of interest to your boss? It’s how you going to help him get the job of his department done? Does your long term goal help in this regard? No it doesn’t. In your day job concentrate on doing your best work there, learn and have that career. Who knows, maybe if you progress you might enjoy it, while your side-hustle might not work out.